# Styling Quasar q-select

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, quasar-framework

I have been wasting a ton of time trying to get this to work but I cannot figure it out for the life of me. I want to change the border color and the text color and the drop down icon. I have used the following style in my scoped component and it makes no change:

```
    .q-field--outlined .q-field__control:before {
       border: 1.25px solid rgb(98 0 255 / 48%);
       transition: border-color 0.36s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    }
```

The text color I can use label-core tag but that does not change the icon color for the dropdown button. So I need a better solution for this. BTW I am only trying to change the color of the text in the input box area not the actual drop down choices panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `q-select` is a child component, scoped styling won't affect it (scoped styling is specifically meant to not leak its styling to child components).

When you do want scoped styling to affect child components, you can use [:deep()](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors)

```css
<style scoped>
:deep(.q-field--outlined .q-field__control:before) {
  border: 1.25px solid rgb(98 0 255 / 48%);
  transition: border-color 0.36s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Now i know why they call you yoduh. One question though to complete this, how do I use custom variables in the quasar.variables.scss file in the label-color area of the q-select. It seems it only accepts the default variables like primary, accent, etc.